# Session invalid. Please log in again appcelerator

Tags: ios, ipad, appcelerator-studio

I started an app project for iOS (iPad) in Appcelerator Studio in 2016.

Now I can't open it in the Simulator or on an iOS device which was no problem last year. In the console it says:

> ERROR: Session invalid. Please log in again.

What is wrong?

I am using the latest versions of Xcode and Appcelerator. 
Titanium SDK: 6.1.0.GA for the project.

Even if I start a new project with only the default files, I get the same error code.

/Nina

Comment: logout and logged in again in studio.

Comment: Session is valid only for 3 days. Ideally, it would have asked to re-login when you launch a studio after a long time. To solve your problem, simply do $appc logout and do $appc login again, still if you've the problem, use $appc logout -D

Answer (score 16):

Open a terminal, enter `appc logout` and hit enter. Once finished enter `appc login` and fill in your Appcelerator credentials. When successfully logged rerun your app and voila :)